# If Cell Contains Specific Text Then Return Value and Sum Row for Scoresheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that takes a selection of choices from a cell and turns it into a "score", then at the end of the row it adds the score up. I know this is not correct but it would be along the lines of

```
=(IF(A2="Red", 1, "")), (IF(A2="Blue", 2, "")), ,(IF(A2="Green", 3, "")), (IF(A2="Yellow", 4, "")), (IF(A3="Oval", 1, "")), (IF(A3="Octagon", 2, "")), (IF(A3="Triangle", 3, "")), (IF(A3="Square", 4, ""))...
```

and then at the end SUM A2:D2.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Basically this is what I'm trying to say use, `=LOOKUP(A2,{"Blue","Green","Red","Yellow"},{2,3,1,4})+LOOKUP(B2,{"Octagon","Oval","Square","Triangle"},{2,1,4,3})+LOOKUP(C2,{"Bank","Church","Playground","School"},{3,1,4,2})+LOOKUP(D2,{"Bank Teller","Doctor","Martial Arts Instructor","Teacher"},{4,1,3,2})`

Comment: Would a value (`Red,Blue,Oval,Church`) ever be listed in more than one question (`Place,Shape,Color`)?

Comment: Each row is the results of a survey - So Color, Shape, Place, and Occupation would not appear more than once in the same row.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya that worked! 

I am only having issues with one line

+LOOKUP(G2,{"Assets in dept and storage","Just in a couple of places","All over and have to search for them"},{1,2,3})

It keeps saying "Did not find value 'All over and have to search for them' in LOOKUP evalution. 

G2 says this "All over and have to search for them"

Comment: Lookup function use Binary searching method, so the Lookup range must be placed in ascending order, then formula become =LOOKUP(G2,{"All over and have to search for them","Assets in dept and storage","Just in a couple of places"},{3,1,2})

Comment: @TanyaPeila as bosco_yip mentioned above ^^^ `LOOKUP()` Function assumes that **lookup_vector** is **sorted** in **ascending order** hence you need to sort the order of the **lookup_vector**, I have also posted a clear explanation on the same, however you can also use `XLOOKUP()` Function as well if you have access to `O365`

Comment: @TanyaPeila so the issue which you are facing is because `Assets`, `Just` and `All` are not sorted it needs to be like `All` then `Assets` and lastly `Just`, this is just in `A-Z` order, you see after `L` comes `S` and after `A` it should be `J`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **explanation** to the formula which I have posted above in comments with few other alternatives, which you may give a try, if you are using **O365**

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=SUM(LOOKUP(A2,{"Blue","Green","Red","Yellow"},{2,3,1,4}),
LOOKUP(B2,{"Octagon","Oval","Square","Triangle"},{2,1,4,3}),
LOOKUP(C2,{"Bank","Church","Playground","School"},{3,1,4,2}),
LOOKUP(D2,{"Bank Teller","Doctor","Martial Arts Instructor","Teacher"},{4,1,3,2}))
```

---

> ***So how does LOOKUP() Function works?***

- The `LOOKUP()` function looksup a value in a one-column or one-row
  range, and retrieve the value from the same position in another
  one-column or one-row range.
- The `LOOKUP()` function has two forms, one is **vector** and another
  is **array**.
- The `LOOKUP()` function accepts three arguments: **lookup_value**,
  **lookup_vector**, and **result_vector**.
- The first argument is  **lookup_value** which is the value to look
  for.
- The second argument is **lookup_vector** which is a one-row, or
  one-column range to search.
- While the third argument which is **result_vector**, is a one-row, or
  one-column range of results.
- **Result_vector** is optional. When **result_vector** is provided, `LOOKUP()` Function locates a match in the **lookup_vector**, and returns the corresponding value from **result_vector**.
- If **result_vector** is not provided, `LOOKUP()` function returns the value of
  the match found in **lookup_vector**.
- `LOOKUP()` Function assumes that **lookup_vector** is **sorted** in **ascending order**.
- `LOOKUP()` Function is **not case-sensitive**.

---

However I assume you have access to **O365** then you may try using the **`[XLOOKUP()][2]`** Function as well, `XLOOKUP()` is a much faster function than anyother lookup function

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(A2,{"Blue","Green","Red","Yellow"},{2,3,1,4}),
XLOOKUP(B2,{"Octagon","Oval","Square","Triangle"},{2,1,4,3}),
XLOOKUP(C2,{"Bank","Church","Playground","School"},{3,1,4,2}),
XLOOKUP(D2,{"Bank Teller","Doctor","Martial Arts Instructor","Teacher"},{4,1,3,2}))
```

---

One more way is to use `LAMBDA()` Function, to create a **custom**, **reusable function** and refer them by a **friendly name**,

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=SumScores(A2,B2,C2,D2)
```

Where,

```
SumScores => 

=LAMBDA(a,b,c,d,
SUM(XLOOKUP(a,{"Blue","Green","Red","Yellow"},{2,3,1,4}),
 XLOOKUP(b,{"Octagon","Oval","Square","Triangle"},{2,1,4,3}),
 XLOOKUP(c,{"Bank","Church","Playground","School"},{3,1,4,2}),
 XLOOKUP(d,{"Bank Teller","Doctor","Martial Arts Instructor","Teacher"},{4,1,3,2})))
```

`LAMBDA()` Function used in **Name Manager** with a **Defined Name** as `SumScores` with syntax as

```
=SumScores(a,b,c,d)
```

---

**EDIT**

> OP mentioned in comments : *So `XLOOKUP()` works perfectly, however, I just found out I am using Slack for my integration and can only use Google Sheet - nooooooo!!!*

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION_GS]

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(VLOOKUP(A2,{"Blue",2;"Green",3;"Red",1;"Yellow",4},2,0),
VLOOKUP(B2,{"Octagon",2;"Oval",1;"Square",4;"Triangle",3},2,0),
VLOOKUP(C2,{"Bank",3;"Church",1;"Playground",4;"School",2},2,0),
VLOOKUP(D2,{"Bank Teller",4;"Doctor",1;"Martial Arts Instructor",3;"Teacher",2},2,0)))
```

---

Comment: So XLOOKUP works perfectly, however, I just found out I am using Slack for my integration and can only use Google Sheet - nooooooo!!!

Comment: aah right let me share the solution for `GS` as well, give me some moment please

Comment: @TanyaPeila i just made in edit, please use the formula as mentioned for `Google Sheet` and do let me know as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula solution based on the OP's layout.

In `E2`, array ("Ctrl"+"Shift"+"Enter") formula copied down :

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<a "&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("' ",,SUBSTITUTE(A$9:D$12," ","_")),"=","='")&"'/>","//@"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","_")&"|//@"&B2&"|//@"&C2&"|//@"&SUBSTITUTE(D2," ","_")))
```

[image]